# df in pyspark looks off indentation

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I read in a file, and updated the schema column name, however, the output seems off. Does anyone know why this happened? and how to fix it?
[image]

read file:
[image]

Comment: The data in your columns here includes the column name.  That's wrong.  The value of the `latutude` column should be `37.5`, not `"latitude": 37.5`.  I don't know how you have managed to do that, since you didn't show us any code at all.

Comment: @TimRoberts I updated how i read in the file, I didn't really change anything except first row

Comment: What does the file look like?  Is it JSON?

Comment: @TimRoberts no specific extension

Comment: I didn't ask what the extension was.  I asked what the file looked like.  That's what determines how it is interpreted.